# About Open MP shared variable

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp

Considering the following code:

```
int counter=0;

#pragma omp parallel 
{
   counter=update(counter);
   /...do something.../
}
```

Does Open MP ensure the update of shared variables is visible to all OMP threads in the parallel region? Or I have to place some sync/barrier to ensure every threads in the pool can always load the latest updated value of shared varaibles?

Comment: The above code do not do any sync work for you, so yes.

Comment: Explicit sync is necessary for all threads to use new updated value for variable **counter**. Anyways you should try n avoid it if possible. As per above code structure, call update() just before the parallel region.